# conda environment broken after updating conda

Tags: pip, anaconda, jupyter, conda, jupyter-lab

after using conda extensively for a while, I was asked to update it yesterday and now things look broken. I have to admit that I am not an expert of what goes on behind the scenes so bear with me :)

After installing conda I used `pip` to install the various packages.
Yesterday I started working on some code from a tutorial on git, which suggested to create an ad-hoc environment to work with:

```
conda env create -f binder/environment.yml
```

At this step I was suggested to update conda, since I was using an old version. I can't find in my terminal that specific message (i.e. I can't find what version of conda I was using before), but here is what I get now when I check the version of conda:

```
(base) francesco ~$ conda list conda
# packages in environment at /Users/francesco/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_anaconda_depends         2019.03                  py36_0  
anaconda                  custom                   py36_1  
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py36_0  
anaconda-navigator        1.8.7                    py36_0  
anaconda-project          0.8.4                      py_0  
conda                     4.8.3                    py36_0  
conda-build               3.10.5                   py36_0  
conda-env                 2.6.0                h36134e3_0  
conda-package-handling    1.6.0            py36h1de35cc_0  
conda-verify              3.4.2                      py_1
```

One of the things I noticed after the update is that in order to activate/deactivate the environment I had to use `conda activate/deactivate <env>` instead of `source activate/deactivate <env>`.

After that I worked with the code in the new environment without any problem.

Today I tried to activate the main environment I work with, but I was asked to "init" my shell first with:

```
conda init bash
```

After that I activated my "usual" environment:

```
conda activate testenv
```

and I tried to start Jupyter Lab, but I got this error:

```
(testenv) francesco ~$ jupyter lab
Error executing Jupyter command 'lab': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What is happening? Why is Jupyter Lab not working anymore in my usual environment?

I checked the installation in `testenv` and things look ok:

```
(testenv) francesco ~$ conda list | grep jup
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7  
jupyter_client            5.2.4                    py37_0  
jupyter_console           6.0.0                    py37_0  
jupyter_core              4.4.0                    py37_0  
(testenv) francesco ~$ pip list | grep jup
jupyter                  1.0.0   
jupyter-client           5.2.4   
jupyter-console          6.0.0   
jupyter-core             4.4.0   
(testenv) francesco ~$
```

Does anyone know what is going on? This is a huge problem for me as conda/jupyter lab are the main tools I use for work :\

Comment: Your `conda list ` output does not show jupyer lab. maybe the update removed it accidentally. try reinstalling it by `conda install jupyterlab`.

Comment: your are right, I reinstalled it and it worked. Isn't it weird though? In principle it might be the case for all the packages I installed in whatever environment I have, right?

Comment: _After installing conda I used [pip] to install the various packages._ Be careful when doing that, see https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/.

Comment: @cel "*accidentally removed it*" sort of doubt it. Looks to me more like they upgraded Conda above v4.4 for the first time, and this takes the *base* env off the `PATH` when other envs are activated. Because the new env didn't install Jupyter Lab, it isn't available; before the upgrade it would have loaded it from **base**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common practice is to only install Jupyter in a single Conda environment (typically your **base** env if an Anaconda user), and always launch Jupyter from there. To use other Python envs in Jupyter, you need to install `ipykernel` in those envs, e.g.,

```
conda install -n testenv ipykernel
```

And, to avoid having to register your additional envs, it is recommended to install `nb_conda_kernels` in the env with Jupyter, e.g.,

```
conda install -n base nb_conda_kernels
```

As a side note, installing things with Pip can make environments unstable. I strongly recommend learning and adhering to [the documented best practices](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#pip-in-env).

Comment: I hadn't seen that part of the documentation about using Pip with Conda, thanks for sharing that! I usually mention https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/ instead.

Comment: I didn't know I could use a single installation of a package in all my environments (e.g. what you suggest to do with JupyterLab). I usually have "complete" environments, meaning that they contain all that it's needed, and then create a kernel based on the environment to be able to use it from inside Jupyter

Comment: @FrancescoLS I should clarify that this does not involve any sharing of packages across environments. Rather, Jupyter is an application that is capable of running different environments within a given notebook. The environments are still isolated.

Answer (score 1):

@FrancescoLS It seems that you had perhaps an older version of Conda installed(?) as the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#440-2017-12-20) indicates that `source activate` was deprecated in favor of `conda activate` in Conda `v4.4.0` (as is also noted in this "[How to Get Ready for the Release of conda 4.4](https://www.anaconda.com/how-to-get-ready-for-the-release-of-conda-4-4/)" post from Anaconda).

This really isn't an "answer" in any actionable way, but it seems that you are not alone in Conda update breaking people's environments.

- [superuser: Conda update conda does extra stuff and destroy my anaconda install](https://superuser.com/questions/1461649/conda-update-conda-does-extra-stuff-and-destroy-my-anaconda-install)
- [Conda Issue #8842: Conda Deletes All Modules During Update](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8842)
- there are lots more. :/

I think it is safe to say that keeping virtual environments safely intact during an upgrade is hard to do, and that when doing a major upgrade across virtual environment maintainers (Conda) it is even harder. This is one of the reasons that I personally try to have all of my project virtual environments be maintained either in native Python 3 `venv` virtual environments with `pip` or through [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) (as they are (or at least used to be) *way* faster to restore than having to go through Conda's slower solver) and then only resorting to using Conda when I need to bring in multiple external binary applications.

Were you able to make a new Conda environment for your work that effectively restores it (perhaps from your own `environment.yml` file for that environment)?